Do not show same day slots- salesforce scheduler
We are implementing salesforce scheduler in a guest community for scheduling appointments. We are using flows that comes with the salesforce scheduler. However, if we want to show available time slots of agents for appointment scheduling, how do we make sure we do not show time slots from the same-day blocking users from creating a same-day appointment.
